# Gradle use plugins and dependencies offline

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, offline

for a presentation I need to compile a a Gradle project offline.
But everything I tried so far to get the dependencies and plugin working offline failed.
What is the recomended way to use Gradle offline and make the plugin and dependecies available before?

here is my current implementation for online use:

```
buildscript {    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE")
    }    
}
```

and

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to build offline (e.g. no network avaiable) using "--offline" option, as described here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_execution_options

I have just tried it and it worked fined, using Gradle v4.9:

- clean/build project,
- shutdown network,
- execute  './gradlew clean build --offline'  => build is OK

Did you try to build with this option? or what other solution did yout try?

Comment: Thanks worked for me too
sorry but I found that option nowhere while trying